# How can I group by data based on specific value ranges using pandas/numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to aggregate data in a pandas series based on its numeric 3 digit ID (101, 234, 531, 232) and I want to find a way that I can create a series with the count of all of the values in the range of hundreds (100 : 1, 200: 2, 500 : 1). Is there any way to do this using numpy/pandas functions instead of just iterating through the series and counting each value individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should give you the correct output:

```
df.groupby(df['id']//100*100).count()
```

Output:

```
    id  
100 1
200 2
500 1
```